# Получить значение из массива по ключу без учета регистра ключа?

Tags: php, case

Пишу класс QueryBuilder для построения запросов к MySQL, по строитель принимает массив с параметрами поиска.

Хочу по ключевому слову допустим `'order by'` получать значение, в каком бы регистре его не передал пользователь хоть `'OrDeR By'`.

Есть ли метод который сможет это реализовать? Или кто сталкивался с данной проблемой подскажите.

**UPDATE**
Пример входного массива:

```
arra1 = array(
    'id' => array('>=', 1),
    'date' => array('<', time()),
    'order by' => array('id', 'DESC'),
    'limit' => array(5, 10),
);
arra2 = array(
    'id' => array('>=', 1),
    'date' => array('<', time()),
    'ORDER BY' => array('id', 'DESC'),
    'LIMIT' => array(5, 10),
);
```

Как зделать что бы и первый масив работали одинаково. Прогнать все поляв нижний регистр нельзя. Остальные ключи кроме `order by` & `limit` поля таблицы.

Comment: [strtolower](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php) поможет?

Comment: А как хранится в массиве значение? Записывайте ключ в массив всегда, к примеру, в нижнем регистре. Тогда при поиске вам просто будет необходимо все параметры приводить в нижний регистр и все

Comment: Registry это реестр. Регистр скорее case. Но лучше соответствующую метку вообще убрать.

Comment: А чем прогонка в нижний регистр имен таблицы может навредить? Разве SQL чувствительно к регистру наименования полей?

Comment: @chubatiy на самом деле некто не когда не будет писать поля таблицы, указываются поля класса, а класс знает какое поле модели какому полю таблицы относится.

Comment: @Makarenko_I_V я понял.  Так а что мешает просто в вашем классе QueryBuilder привести их в нижний регистр? Только для того, чтобы можно потом было найти соответствие в поле модели?

Comment: @Chubatiy после того как они найдены их нужно ансетнуть что бы QueryBuilder не пытался найти соответствующие поля модели.

Comment: Для MySQL/PostgreSQL синтакс не чуствителен к регистру поэтому `SELECT * FROM users  OrDer by id;` и `SELECT * FROM users order by id;` сработают одинаково.

Comment: @E_p мне кажется Вы не дочитали до конца. У меня  есть массив с данными, как мне узнать есть ли значения по всем возможным ключам строки в не зависимости от регистра.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$a = [
    'a'=>'0',
    'A'=>'1',
    'b'=>'2',
    'ZyX'=>'3',
    'HELLO'=>'4',
    'Я'=>'5',
];

$arrayKeys = array_keys($a);
$keyMap = array_combine($arrayKeys, $arrayKeys);
$tmpArray = array_change_key_case($keyMap, CASE_LOWER);

unset($a[$tmpArray['hello']]);
unset($a[$tmpArray['zyx']]);
unset($a[$tmpArray['a']]);
```

Можете попробовать так. Но тут есть два момента.

1. Дубликаты в разных регистрах смержатся
2. Ключи с кириллицей обрабатывают некорректно.

Но сама идея думаю понятна, хотя если будут браться имена классов то думаю это не проблема

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно, надеюсь работает шустренько.

Answer (score -2):

Наверное так

```
$testArray = array('KeYmLoVer' => 1);

function getArrayValue($key,$array) {
   foreach($testArray as $_key=>$_val) {
     if(strtolower($_key) == strtolower($key)) {
       return $_val;
     }
   }
}

echo getArrayValue('keymlover',$array);
```

Но лучше, раз пройтись по массиву и переписать ключи в lowercase.

Comment: Читайте внимательно, я говорил что все параметры кроме limit и order by являются полями таблицы и им обезательно необходимо сохранять регистр!